# QML ChartView with DateTimeAxis not able to plot seconds

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick, qchartview

I am trying to show `ChartView`, with X axis as `hh:mm` so I am using `DateTimeAxis`.
As per the `DateTimeAxis` we need to provide min and max as JavaScript `Date()` object.
I want to have the hh:mm to range between `00:00` to `05:00` so I am using below code.

```
ChartView { 

ValueAxis {
   id: chartYAxis
   min: 0
   max: 400
   color: "#8c8a89"
   labelsColor: "#9c9998"
   labelFormat: "%d"
   tickCount: 5
   titleText: "Y Axis"
   gridLineColor: "gray"
   titleFont.pointSize: 10
}

DateTimeAxis {
   id: chartXAxis
   min: new Date(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0) // 00:00
   max: new Date(1970, 1, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0) // 05:00
   format: "hh:mm"
   tickCount: 6
   labelsColor: "white"
   gridVisible: false
   lineVisible: true
   titleText: "Time (hh:mm)"
   titleFont.pointSize: 10
}

SplineSeries {
   id: spline1
   name: "line1"
   color: "white"
   width: 2
   axisX: chartXAxis
   axisY: chartYAxis
}

}
```

But the time for X axis that I am receiving is in seconds, not epoch seconds.
For example I receive X axis time in seconds as: [400, 5000, 60, 9000, 10000]
I am not sure how to plot these on the X axis I tried to append to `spline1` as X, Y but no luck.
When I plot these seconds on the Chart then I don't see the line graph.
Do I need to convert seconds to epoch?

Comment: did you try  to convert seconds to epoch?

Comment: @folibis Yes I am able to plot them if I convert them to epoch using the `var tdate = Date(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0); tdate.setSeconds(sec); ` and then plot them on the chart. But is there a better way rather then using `1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0`, I want to manipulate only hours and minutes.